# How can I create an image with television effect?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to process an image with the television effect. Here is the link for sample processed image http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/RedMatterLibrary/village_waves_1.jpg

Can someone please tell me if openCV library can do this? or there are any other libraries which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: OpenCV is a low level processing library, so the answer is yes, if only you spend some time to simulate the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can manipulate the pixels. So you just need to write such a filter yourself.
Here is something I came up with. Maybe you can tweak it to your likeing.

It takes an image, desaturates the colors a little and then increases the blue part according to a vertical sine function.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <highgui.h> 
#include <cmath>

double wavelength = 40;
double intensity = 0.5;

double decolorisation = 0.7;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat img = imread(argv[1]);
    cv::Mat outImg = img.clone();

    for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++)
        {
            // desaturate the image
            double meanColor = (img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] + img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] + img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[3]) / 3.0;
            cv::Vec3b newColor;
            newColor[0] = (1-decolorisation)*img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] + decolorisation*meanColor; 
            newColor[1] = (1-decolorisation)*img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] + decolorisation*meanColor; 
            newColor[2] = (1-decolorisation)*img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] + decolorisation*meanColor; 

            // boost the blue channel
            double coeff = 0.5 + sin((2*M_PI*i)/wavelength)/2.0;
            newColor[0] = newColor[0] + intensity * coeff * (255-newColor[0]);

            outImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = newColor;
        }

    cv::imshow("Original",img);
    cv::imshow("Televised",outImg);
    waitKey(0);          
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing it and will let you know.